# How to automatically download Calameo SWF files and convert to PDF

Tags: python, flash, pdf, converters

i registered to some website and the content it is providing is through Calameo.com flash-swf viewer.

Their swf viewer also implements a "Send To Printer" mechanism and with that i can save the content in a PDF format.

I want to automatically give a url to one of the web pages containing the SWF, and from there to automatically obtain the PDF file format somehow.. (In any possible way)

I thought maybe i i download the SWF file it would be helpful but i am not sure how to work with that (Its actually an SWC - Compressed swf file)

Does anyone have any idea how to work with that?
Here is a url example
http://v.calameo.com/?bkcode=002612871a4d82c030cf5&mode=viewer&showsharemenu=false&authid=kwhozXIDHt1i

I'd prefer a python code to do it, but anything else could also work

There was once an online service (http://calameo-pdf-download.abuouday.com/) which was supposed to do exactly that, but it seems like it is not working anymore

Any help appreciated :)